# The number of ways of going up 7 steps ...

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The number of ways of going up 7 steps if we take one or two steps at a time is ?

So its essentially asking in how many ways can we make use of numbers of (1,2) to get a sum of 7.

Comment: It seems you've posted three questions now, all within a relatively short period of time, each of which is nothing more than a problem statement. The expectation is that if you have a question to ask, that you take a little time explaining what you've tried, where you're stuck, what you think you need to use (methods, theorems, etc) or how this is similar to or different from a problem you can answer.

Comment: sorry I am new here. Ill edit my question to suit the prerequisites

Comment: That's better, and yes, how many ways can we form a sum of $7$ using only the numbers $1, 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

$$
21
$$

So there are four different ways to get $7$ with just $1$ and $2$ which are:
$$
1+1+1+1+1+1+1
$$
$$1+1+1+1+1+2
$$
$$1+1+1+2+2$$
$$1+2+2+2$$
But we want to know how many ways we can rearrange these.

For the first case with all $1$s whichever way we look at it, we are taking seven single steps one after the other so there is only one rearrangement.

For the second case all that is important is where the $2$ occurs, there are six possible places it could occur so there are six different ways to make the $7$ steps.

Similarly for the last case, there are $4$ numbers and only one $1$ so all that is important is the position of the 1, so there are 4 rearrangements here.

Lastly (the hardest case) is the third one. The way I approached this was to say there are $5$ numbers here and two $2$s, so there are five places for the first $2$, four places for the second $2$ so that gives us $4 \cdot 5 = 20$ ways to rearrange this...but it doesn't because we have double counted: interchanging the two $2$s gives us the same rearrangement, so we need to divide by two, giving us $10$ ways to rearrange 
$$
1+1+1+2+2$$

So adding this all up we have $21$ different ways to take seven steps taking $1$ and $2$ steps at a time.

EDIT:

Another more fun method as suggested by user21820 is as follows:

When we have only 1 step to climb there is only one method, and when we have two steps to climb there are two methods.

Now let $F_n$ be the nth Fibonacci number and like $S_n$ be the number of ways to climb the stairs.

We claim $F_n = S_n$. This is true in the base cases $n = 1,2$ and assume it is true whenever $n$ is less than $m$.

Now when we have $m$ steps then every way of climbing these steps is one of the following two cases:

A way to climb $m-1$ steps with a 1 added at the end OR a way to climb $m-2$ stairs with a 2 added at the end. Not that a way to climb $m$ stairs is in exactly one of these categories.

So

$S_m = S_{m-1} + S_{m-2} = F_{m-1}+F_{m-2} = F_m$

So by induction the way to climb $n$ stairs in jumps of 1 or 2 stairs is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Are you aware that $21$ is a Fibonacci number and it is no coincidence?

Comment: @user21820 if this is aimed at me, then yes I'm aware of the relation between compositions of n into $1$s and $2$s and I'm fairly tempted to add that method to my answer...

Comment: I was wondering why you didn't mention it, because we can then get the answer much more efficiently just from the recurrence itself.

Comment: Well based on the phrasing of the question from the OP it seemed like they would probably find this style of answer than a long winded induction calculation. They only asked for the case when there are cool seven steps than when there are n.

Comment: Well it's a good example of recurrence relations. =)